# How can I make an array or variable for an if statement in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, input

I am trying to make a login system using `if` statements and input values and I want to know if there is a way I can create something like an array or variable or object that I can put all the passwords and usernames in and that I can also add new ones easily. I am not actually using this for a website; it is just a project. Thank you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.login').click(function(){
        var userResult = $('input[name=userInput]').val();
        var passResult = $('input[name=passInput]').val();
        if(userResult === "CodeAcademy" && passResult === "fun-coding" || userResult === "User_Example" && passResult === "Pass_Example")
        {
          //Some stuff that will happen
        }
    });
});
```

FYI `userInput` and `passInput` are the input boxes that the user puts their username and password into.

Comment: You can put username- password pair into an array. `var myArray = [{username: "user1", password:"p1"}, {username: "user2", password:"p2"}];`

Comment: Your question is sufficiently answered below. I know you mentioned it not being used as a website. I thought it worth mentioning that keeping anything to do with password authentication or a password database in clientside javascript is not a good idea as anyone is able to read the passwords.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid long chains of logic, array iteration, extra string quotes, and slow searching by using a look-up table Object to store many logins and passwords in one simple little data structure:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.login').click(function(){
        var userResult = $('input[name=userInput]').val();
        var passResult = $('input[name=passInput]').val();
        if({  // username     password
               CodeAcademy:  "fun-coding", 
               User_Example: "Pass_Example",
               "User with space": "sOmeP@ssw0rd",
        }[  userResult  ] === passResult ){ // user valid and password match?
            alert("authenticated"); //Some stuff that will happen
        }//end if valid user?
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of login objects using a separate form, and using `grep` to search through this array to see if there is a matching user. Here is demo https://jsfiddle.net/f4aqmt4e/

Below is the code and the explanation:

```
var myLogins = [];//this might be object that you store the login information

//lets say when a new user registers you keep record of their login information in myLogins
//first create the login information
var myLogin = new Object();
myLogin.Username = "myusername";
myLogin.Password= "12345";

//then add the login information to the login-store array
myLogins.push(myLogin);


 $('.login').click(function(){
    var userResult = $('input[name=userInput]').val();
    var passResult = $('input[name=passInput]').val();

    //grep will help you to find a certain element within an array based on a condition
    //we will use grep to see if there a matching login info
    var loginresult = $.grep(myLogins, function(e){ return e.Username == userResult  && e.Password == passResult ; });

    if(loginresult.lenght)
    {
       //login successful
    }else {
       //login failed
    }   
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  var vals = [
    ["CodeAcademy", "User_Example"],
    ["fun-coding", "Pass_Example"]
  ];
  
  $(".login").click(function() {

    var res = $("._login").toArray().every(function(el, i) {
      return i === 0 
             ? $.inArray(el.value, vals[i]) !== -1 // name
             : $.inArray(el.value, vals[i]) !== -1 // pass
    });

    if (res) {
      // do stuff
      alert("login successful")
    };

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input name="userInput" type="text" class="_login" />
<input name="passInput" type="text" class="_login" />
<input type="button" class="login" value="login" />
```